# If $|f(z)|\leq e^{Rez}$ for all $|z|>k>0$ then $f(z)=ae^z$ for each $z\in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be entire such that $|f(z)|\leq e^{Rez}$ for all $|z|>k>0$. I need to prove that $f(z)=ae^z$ for each $z\in \mathbb{C}$ where $k,a\in \mathbb{R}$. This I find very difficult and have no idea even where to start from. Any hints will be very helpful thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function $e^{-z}f(z)$ is bounded by $1$ for $|z| > k$ and bounded by some number $M$ for $|z| \le k$ (since a continuous function on a compact set is bounded). So if $r := \max\{1,M\}$, then $e^{-z}f(z)$ is bounded by $r$ in $\Bbb C$. Now apply Liouville's theorem to $e^{-z}f(z)$.